# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/extension/mysqli.so'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli, dynamic

Just setting up laravel 8. In the cmd, it's showing this warning again and again. Laravel is installed and working perfectly but my question is that is this going to be a problem? do I have to install it again?

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/extension/mysqli.so' (tried: /path/to/extension/mysqli.so (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_/path/to/extension/mysqli.so.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/extension/mysqli.so' (tried: /path/to/extension/mysqli.so (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_/path/to/extension/mysqli.so.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: As the error says, it is trying to load `mysqli.so` on `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_/path/to/extension/` but it clearly does not exist. And reading `/path/to/extension/`, I am pretty sure there is a misconfiguration from you or a copy paste...

Comment: How can I solve it?